# Index out of rage cannot be resolved [ASP.NET Core]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I got the following code:

```
//getting skills from DB
var skills = this.db.HumanSkills.Where(r => r.HumanId == model.Id).Include(x => x.Skill).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < model.Skills.Count; i++) //iterating over the list. Boundary set to i < model.Skills.Count this is number of elements in my viewmodel (model.Skills) using which I am going to update Name property of my DB elements.
            {
                if (skills[i] != null) //index out of range here. Why?
                {
                    //here I update DB skill names using model skill names
                    skills[i].Skill.Name = model.Skills[i].Skill.Name;
                }
                else //here I create new Skill for every element of the DB skill list that doesn't exist
                {
                    var newSkill = new HumanSkill { Skill = model.Skills[i].Skill, Human = currentHuman };

                    this.db.Add(newSkill);
                    this.db.SaveChanges(); //yes, I know it's not a good practice to execute it each time, but otherwise rows in my HumanSkills table are not sorted.
                }

            }
```

On line:
`if (skills[i] != null) //index out of range here. Why?`

I am getting index out of range, even though I use `!=null`

Comment: The obvious answer is that `skills.Count` is less than `model.Skills.Count`.

Comment: Why `!=null` doesn't catch the exception?

Comment: indexing out of the range will not return null, but will throw an exception, as you have experienced.

Comment: you can catch an exception with the catch keyword, read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/

Comment: How can I code if `skills[i]` doesn't exist go to the `else` block?

Comment: It is demonstrated in the documentation I referenced.

Comment: @fbede, I will take a look at the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Can it be done without `try` `catch` block?

Comment: you could try if (i < skills.Count) as the condition for the if statement, however there are other issues with your code as well. You do not seem to handle deletion from you list and making the items sorted via multiple SaveChanges call is very wasteful, breaks atomicity and most likely doesn't even work with parallel request to the same resource.

Comment: @fbede, I agree. How can I sort the items in the intermediary table without using SaveChanges? If I don't use SaveChanges rows in the intermediary table `HumanSkills` are not added sequentially.

Comment: if you really need them sorted I would create an increasing Index property for the model, and save the items with the correct Index values. However if you only want them ordered for this endpoint to work as it works now, I would rather rewrite  it with a different approach.

Comment: If you really are trying to update a list with another list, I would probably implement it somehow like this: https://gist.github.com/fbede4/e5fad1d9d264ca3e19de4969ad7060a4 . It is untested, just to show the approach.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that **var skills** is a different object than **model.Skills**

Comment: They are of the same type `HumanSkill`.

Comment: Yes, the same type, but apparently a different number of items

Answer (score 0):

"var skills" and "model.Skills" are 2 different variables.
There are of the same type, but it's 2 differents objects!

You can do that :

```
IEnumerable<Skill> skillsList = this.db.HumanSkills.Where(r => r.HumanId == model.Id).Include(x => x.Skill).ToList();
foreach (Skill s in skillsList)
{
   // your logic... or debug.print for check how many items are get from the db
}
```

Comment: I use `model.Skills` because I update Name property of all elements in `db.HumanSkill`.

Comment: Ok, but can you please show me all the code of you method/function?
Or have you a git?